# Force parameterized type as constructor parameter to be correct

Tags: java, generics

I have been searching for quite a while on this, and nothing really comes close to what I need.

Example code:

```
public class MyQueue<E extends Delayed & Serializable> extends DelayQueue<E> {
    private Class<E> mClass;
    public MyQueue(Class<E> type) {
        super();
        mClass = type;
    }
}
```

MyQueue is created like: `MyQueue q<MyObj> = new MyQueue<MyObj>(MyObj.class);`.

My question: How can I write the constructor in such a way, that the parameter "type" is of the proper parameterized type "E extends Delayed & Serializable"?

I hope I have explained myself allright.

Thank you in advance for any assistance.

**Edit**: From the answers and remarks I was at first unable to select a proper answer. So for the first time I shall try to enhance my question with what I wanted in the first place, and what I am ending up with now. Eg answering in the original post what I have found.

Obviously what I need to know, is the class of the parameterized type E on construction time. For transparancy, the queue is using the E class name (being MyObj) to pass to a backing store. After a lot of reading I came to understand that I could not get at this information easier because of type erasure. I was forced to pass the class not only as a parameterized type, but also as a constructor variable.

I was afraid I could, by accident, call the constructor as such (MyObj and OthrObj both implement Delayed & Serializable):

```
MyQueue q<MyObj> = new MyQueue<MyObj>(OthrObj.Class);
```

**My better question should have been**: ***How can I write the constructor in such a way, forcing the constructor variable E to match the parameterized type E?***

It would have made so much more sense, and it probably would have been easier to understand what I have written. Technically most of you are right in some sense, and after testing many of the variations, I came to the conclusion I have already done so *giggles sorry* seh and Tnem are completly right and both deserve the credits.

Comment: Could you not simply specify the parameter as being of type E?

Comment: It looks like you're already there. If type `MyObj` does not derive from both `Delayed` and `Serializable`, the binding of `MyObj` to type parameter `E` would fail.

Comment: Do you want a class object as parameter? Or are you interested in an object of type E? Could you show us the error message you are seeing?

Comment: `type` can never be of type `E` because you are not receiving an instance of `E` in the constructor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you have written is what you have specified, the `type` parameter will be enforced to be of type `Delayed & Serializable`. I can't see what is wrong here...

Answer (score 3):

You **have** already written 'the constructor in such a way, that the parameter "type" is of the proper parameterized type "E extends Delayed & Serializable"'.

The type restriction from the class definition itself

```
public class MyQueue<E extends Delayed & Serializable> ...
```

carries through. You don't repeat the upper bounds for the type in the constructor definition

```
public MyQueue(Class<E> type) {
```

and it's not necessary. E.g. an instantiation like

```
MyQueue<Long> myQueue = new MyQueue<Long>(Long.class);
```

results in a compiler error. - Just try it.

Comment: No, `type` in this case is `Class<E>`, not `E`

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is like:

```
public class MyQueue<E extends Delayed & Serializable> extends DelayQueue<E> {
    private E mClass;
    public MyQueue(E type) {
        super();
        mClass = type;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but this is passing an instance of E. I need the class of E.

Answer (score 0):

```
public MyQueue(Class<E> type) {
    super();
    mClass = type;
    type.asSubclass(Delayed.class);
    type.asSubclass(Serializable.class);//both of these throw when it can't happen
}
```

this explicitly check whether the class passed is correct even when accounting type erasure (and throws classcastexception when it cant happen)